# gulp-imagemin does not work

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I want to compress the images and pipe to the directory of dist,but the dist is empty after run the task.
this is my task

```
gulp.task("minify_img", function() {
  gulp.src("src/img/*")
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("/dist/img"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return gulp.src("src/img/*");
```

Comment: Hello & Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the tour, and [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)?

Answer (score 0):

With your current destination path `/dist/img`, the files will be at the root of your drive (e.g. `D:/dist/img`). You should add a dot before it, then the files will be exported to the root of your project.

```
.pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/img"));
```

Comment: I have tried but the result no changes.Is the version of gulp-imagemin makes it?

Comment: @zhaohe `gulp.src` let's try with only one image to see if it works.

Comment: Did you try "dist/img" ? Also you can launch pipe(debug()) (install gulp-debug to use it) to see what happens...

Comment: Same issue here. Any solution?